# Using a specific AD account with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We are using Entity Framework (4.1 Code First) in some ASP.NET MVC websites that are using Windows Authentication and Impersonation.

The problem is that I need to connect to SqlServer with a specific AD account (and not the impersonated one). How can I do that with EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really related to EF because EF simply use ADO.NET to connect to database and ADO.NET uses either current account (integrated security) or SQL account (which is btw. more clear solution for your problem).

If you need to use special account you must manually impersonate the account for some operations which is actually little problem because .NET doesn't provide method for directly log-in as another user to gets her windows identity needed for impersonation. You must use [small P/Invoke to WinAPI](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/impersonate-user-aspnet).

Comment: imho it's a EF problem since EF wraps the connection management. I need to inject into the connection creation in some way to be able to use impersonation

Comment: @jgaufin: DbContext has a constructor overload taking an existing collection, so you can inject it easily.

Comment: Marking it as the answer since it made me realize that it isn't work the trouble. I've recoded parts of our framework to not rely on impersonation (and use a p/invoke wrapper class when it's really needed).

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do that you will have to manage the EF connections manually and supply the needed account/login information manually.

Some useful information on how to do this:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.connection.aspx